# Visa for Belgium visit as well as business meeting

Tags: schengen-visas, belgium

I will be visiting Belgium on business trip and intend to visit my daughter who is doing PhD in Belgium.

Comment: and your question is... ?

Comment: If you already have a visa for your business trip, I don't see why you couldn't see your daughter while being there.

Comment: The default visa is for visting. When BNL 13 has been added also for business.

Comment: My business trip will be for 5 days. The visa issued will be valid for how many days??

Comment: The duration of the visa depends on the itinerary you submit with the application.  If you plan to remain in Belgium after the conclusion of your business trip so you can spend time with your daughter then you should say as much in your application.

Comment: Ali, please sign into the account you used to ask this question (or have the two accounts merged) and you can edit or add comments to the question.